# Land Rover in Mongolia with no hired driver

Tags: driving, car-rentals, mongolia, off-road

I am planning to visit Mongolia next year, mainly for wildlife and I wonder if it is possible to rent a Land Rover and drive it on our own, without hiring a driver.  Is this possible?

Comment: Fine in what way? What are you asking?  If you will be permitted to rent it?

Comment: Hi @Flimzy, my doubt is if it's one of this countries you are prompted to hire a driver (even if it was only in some areas)or at least most of the people recommend so. From what I read is not the first case but I have seen some pages in the sense of recommending hiring a driver. Which I would like to avoid but not at any cost

Comment: Specifically a Land Rover? Or any kind of off-road vehicle would do just as well?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any legal issue with having no driver/guide as I know it is a popular place for Motorcyclists thanks to The Long Way Round. The Mongol Rally also travels there from London and it doesn't require any driver or guides for that section.

Here is a Link to the Lonely Planet Guide on traveling in Mongolia

http://www.lonelyplanet.com/mongolia/transport/getting-around

Here is also a link to the Mongol Rally page. You could try sending them an email to clarify the legality of traveling without a guide.

http://www.theadventurists.com/the-adventures/mongol-rally